# How can you use getline to input values to classes in C++?

Tags: c++

I thought I have done everything correctly to make this work, but I get these errors:

..\CS115_IP2_SolJohnston.cpp:107:2: error: 'Customer1' was not declared in this scope
  Customer1.setCustName("");
  ^

..\CS115_IP2_SolJohnston.cpp:152:29: error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}' to 'Customer*' for argument '1' to 'void viewAddress(Customer*)'
    viewAddress(name, address);
                             ^

```
 void displayMenu(string userName)
{

    cout << userName << ", please select an action from the menu below" << endl;

    cout<<"My Menu";
    cout<<"========" << endl;
    cout<<"0 - View Your Order Name and Address" << endl;

    cout<<"X - Exit " <<endl<<endl;
}
class Customer
{
    private:
    string CustName;
    string CustAddress;

    public:
    void setCustName(string);
    string getCustName();

    void setCustAddress(string);
    string getCustAddress();

    // Constructor
    // create empty placeholders
    Customer();
};

//definition of set/get member functions of Employee class
void Customer::setCustName(string name){CustName=name;}

void Customer::setCustAddress(string address){CustAddress=address;}

string Customer::getCustName() { return CustName; }

string Customer::getCustAddress() { return CustAddress; }


Customer::Customer()
{
    CustName = "";
    CustAddress = "";

}

void viewAddress(Customer *Cust)
{
    cout << "Name: " << Cust->getCustName() << endl;
    cout << "Address: " << Cust->getCustAddress() << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
Customer1.setCustName("");
Customer1.setCustAddress("");

string name = "";
string address = "";

cout << "Please enter your Address:  street, city, state==> ";
getline(cin, address);
Customer1.setCustAddress(address);



cout << "Hello "+ name + " from " + address << endl;

do
    {
    // display menu
    displayMenu(name);
    // read user selection
    cin>>selection;
    switch(selection)
        {
        case '0':
            cout<< "Your Address is" << endl;
            viewAddress(name, address);
            break;
            case 'X' :
        case 'x':
            cout<<"Thank you!!!" << endl;
            break;
        default : cout<<"Invalid selection. Please try again";
        // no break in the default case
        }
        cout<<endl<<endl;
    } while (selection!= 'X' && selection != 'x');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Everything after the closing `}` of `viewAddress` belongs in a *function* (like `main()`).

Comment: I just added that and will update the question.  It still has the error, but it does help it to add that doesn't it :)

Comment: I think you need to declare Customer1 as type 'Customer' before attempting to use it.

Comment: I just set that Customer Customer1;,  I can't believe I forgot that!

Comment: Originally I have had problems when I had this working with the line: getline(cin, address);
Customer1.setCustAddress(address);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to use an undeclared object in main `customer1`. so declare an object of type Customer then use it.

```
int main()
{
     Customer customer1; // instantiate Customer class
    Customer1.setCustName("");
    Customer1.setCustAddress("");

}
```

Comment: also declare `char selection;` before using it. also pass the address of `Customer1` to `ViewAddress()` not two strings: `ViewAddress(&Customer1);`

Comment: This really helped my understanding.  :)